# How to download and add XML layout and Java Code files in android without reinstalling app?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, plugin-architecture

I want to extend the features of my android app by adding few screens in the app when the user chooses to download the screens and without making the user reinstall or upgrade the app. I have explored the option of making the user install another android app which will act as a plugin, but I want to avoid forcing the user to install another app via google play as he can he reluctant.

Is there a way download only the required XML layout and attached java code file only?

Answer (score 0):

You can try create a ActivityHolder (cause Activity must be declared on Manifest) and use a Interface to implement the methods from Activity, use the getClassLoader().loadClass to instantiate your file and hold the instance of it in the activity.

And you cant use XML layout cause the ids are generated in compile time into the class .R.

Worth trying.